# How do I include untyped-JavaScript, from an adjacent file, in ReasonML bindings?

Tags: javascript, ocaml, reason, bucklescript, reason-react

While trying to get started with Reason, in one JavaScript project, I've got an extremely light file that tries to be a Reason-typed interface to the existing, heavy, library:

```
/* TheLibrary.re */
type engine

external addEngine : string -> engine -> unit = "" [@@bs.val] [@@bs.module "../"]
```

However, when I try to *use* that library in a ReasonReact project (having added `@org/the-library` to the `bsconfig.json` `bs-dependencies`),

```
/* AComponent.re */
[@bs.val] [@bs.module "@org/game-engine/dist/game-engine.js"]
   external gameEngine : TheLibrary.engine = "default";

/* Further down, a React lifecycle method, */
TheLibrary.addEngine("Game", gameEngine);
```

I get errors about `../` being not found, **relative to that React component**:

```
./src/components/main-menu/AComponent.re
Module not found: Can't resolve '../' in '/Users/ec/Work/reason-reacty/src/components/main-menu'
```

I've also tried, instead of `../` in `TheLibrary.re`'s `external` declaration:

1. `@bs.module "./index.js"` (the direct, ES6 entry-point for the untyped-JavaScript side of the package in question,)
2. `@bs.module "@org/the-library"`, the entire name of said library (even though I'm typing *inside* that library???)

Please help! I'd love to be able to further adopt ML, but I'm having the hardest time wrapping my head around ReasonReact's dependency-resolution!

---

Additional context:

So, we're trying to build our first ReasonReact project, and we've successfully added baby's-first-opaque-types to one of our internal libraries and include that in the ReasonReact page with something like the following — which *works*, by the way:

```
/* Imports.re */
type engine;

[@bs.val] [@bs.module "@org/game-engine/dist/game-engine.js"]
   external gameEngine : engine = "default";
[@bs.val] [@bs.module "@org/the-library"] [@bs.scope "default"]
   external addEngine : (string, engine) => unit = "";
```

This yields, when we `Imports.(addEngine("Game", gameEngine))`, the global setup line we need: `TheLibrary.addEngine("Game", GameEngine)`. I'm in the very first stages of trying to upstream that typing-information into the parent project, and publish that code to npm, so that *all* consuming projects can start to use Reason.

Comment: (Forgive the Reason syntax, if you, like me, find it a little hard to read — trying to appeal to those who know the ReasonReact resolution most thoroughly .)

Comment: Glenn's answer clarifies a lot of things but, could you clarify what happens when you try option (2)? It seems like it should work. Like Glenn said, BuckleScript generates module requires/imports in the _consuming_ module, so from the perspective of the _consuming_ module, something like `require('@org/the-library')` should be correct.

Answer (score 2):

t sounds like you might be a bit confused about the different tools that make up your toolchain, so let's first go through them one by one to put them in their place:

- **ReasonReact** is a library of opinionated, "thick" bindings to react.js, which despite the name isn't actually all that Reason-specific, except for its integration with Reason's JSX syntax. It would be more accurate to call it a BuckleScript library.
- **Reason** is mostly just the syntax you use, but is often also used more broadly to refer to the ecosystem around it, and usually also imply that BuckleScript is being used.
- **OCaml** is the underlying language. The "semantics" of Reason, if you will.
- **BuckleScript** is the OCaml-to-JavaScript compiler. It compiles ONE source file, which is considered a module, into ONE JavaScript module, but also requires the type information of other OCaml modules as input.

Now, I suspect you already know most of that, but what you do not seem to know is that NONE of these actually do ANY dependency resolution. These next parts of your toolchain are what does that:

- **The BuckleScript Build System**, or **bsb**, is what finds all the modules in your local project according to what you've specified in `src` and any BuckleScript libraries you've listed in `bs-dependecies` in `bsconfig.json`. It will figure out the dependency order of all these and feed them to the compiler in the correct order to produce one JavaScript module for each OCaml module (along with some other artefacts containing type information and such). But it will not resolve any JavaScript dependencies.
- Lastly, **webpack**, or some other JavaScript **bundler**, is what you likely use to combine all the JavaScript modules into a single file, and which therefore needs to resolve any JavaScript dependencies. And this is likely where the error message comes from.

Using `[@bs.module "some-module"]` will make the BuckleScript compiler emit `var ... = require('some-module')` (or `import ... from 'some-module'` if es6 is used), but BuckleScript itself will not do anything more with it. The string you pass to `@bs.module` is the same string you would pass to `require` if it had been an ordinary CommonJS module (or whatever other module format you have configured).

Also note that the import is not emitted where the `external` is defined, but where it's used. You can work around, or "ground" it in a module by re-exporting it as an ordinary definition, ie. `let addEngine = addEngine`.

In order to precisely answer your question I would need to know which bundler you use, where you've configured BuckleScript to output its JavaScript artefacts, where the externals are used, not just defined, and where the external JavaScript module is located. But I hope all this underlying knowledge will make it easy for you and future readers to identify and resolve the problem yourself. If you're still a bit unsure, look at the compiled JavaScript artefacts and just treat them as ordinary JavaScript modules. At this point that's really all they are.